# What do you call a mildly-context sensitive grammar in which the LHS must appear in the grammar spec?

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

For instance:
$$
S \rightarrow aAbAb \\
aAb \rightarrow AAa \\
A \rightarrow Aa | a
$$
$aAb$ is alright to have on the left-hand side since it occurs directly in the grammar spec.  Further indirectly created sentential forms with $aAb$ are not expanded but become non-terminating.  This makes it easier to parse than a general context-sensitive grammar because you know the valid occurrences beforehand.  If this grammar can somehow be reduced to a context-free grammar, I'm not interested because I've found use for specifying the grammar this way.